How can the equation Delta G = -RTln(K_eq) + RTln(Q) yield positive values if K_eq is already the lowest energy possible?
My understanding may be faulty, but this is what I'm thinking:
$$\Delta\text{G}=\text{G}_\text{final}-\text{G}_\text{initial}$$If now I replace $\ce{G_{final}}$ with $\ce{G_{eq}}$, or the free energy of the system at equilibrium, I get that $$\ce{\Delta G = G_{eq} - G_{initial}}$$We know that the equilibrium condition is where the free energy of the system must be at its minimum. Thus, using this equation we can conclude that if $\ce{G_{final} = G_{eq}}$, then regardless of what $\ce{G_{initial}}$ is, it must always be $\geq\ce{G_{eq}}$. Then, by definition whenever $\ce{\Delta G = G_{eq} - G_{initial}}$, $\ce{\Delta G \leq 0}$.
Moving on, the equation $\ce{\Delta G = -RT\ln(K_{eq}) - \left(-RT\ln(Q)\right)}$ tells me that I can find out the spontaneity of a reaction based on its initial and equilibrium conditions. Then, is it not fair to say that $\ce{\Delta G_{eq}}$ can be represented by $\ce{-RT\ln(K_{eq})}$ since $\ce{K_{eq}}$ is infact the equilibrium condition and $\ce{\Delta G_{initial}}$ can be represented by $\ce{-RT\ln(Q)}$ since $\ce{Q}$ is the initial condition?
If we accept this, we must accept that since the equation $\ce{\Delta G = \Delta G^{\circ} + RT\ln(Q)}$ can be both positive and negative, it becomes possible for an initial condition given by $\text{Q}$ to be lower in energy compared to $\ce{K_{eq}}$. I am getting this because when $\ce{\Delta G > 0}$:$$\ce{RT\ln(Q) > RT\ln(K_{eq})\implies-RT\ln(Q) < -RT\ln(K_{eq})\implies G_{initial} < G_{eq}}$$I understand that this means that the forward reaction is non-spontaneous, and I also understand why that is. However, my question is based on the energy implications of this process. If I am making logical leaps, please feel free to say so. I am just confused how it is that to move towards the equilibrium condition, I must gain free energy and thus move to a higher energy state when in fact equilibrium is supposed to be the lowest energy state attainable by the system.
Help would be appreciated :)

Consider $\Delta_\text{r} G = \Delta_\text{r} G^\circ + RT \ln{Q}=\dfrac{dG}{d\xi}$ where $\xi \text{[mol]}$ is the reaction extent.

You often use extra tags \text or \ce to keep quantity symbols upright, but that is wrong. As rule of thumb, symbols for quantities, variables and physical constants should be in italic as the Matjsx default.  // Upright vs Italics

Possibly helpful: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/4/gibbs-free-energy-minimum-or-zero

Also: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/173557/what-is-the-basis-for-the-relationship-of-gibbs-energy-and-extent-of-reaction-sh/173569#173569
